# Warning: Extra attributes from the server: style

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, jsx

In my Next.js application I am getting this warning:

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: style
```

I have no idea where this is happening so don't have any code to show.

Comment: Do you have the lastpass browser extension? Try disabling it if you do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, turns out adding style directly to the `<body>` in the `layout.tsx` causes it

```
...

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode}) {

 return(
    <html lang="en">
       <body style={{ display: "flex" }}>
         ...
       </body>
    </html>
 )

}
```

[image]

---

To solve it, create a separate `styles.css` file -> add the body styles to it -> import it into the `layout.tsx`

**styles.css :**

```
body {
    display: flex;
}
```

**layout.tsx :**

```
...

import "./globals.css"

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode}) {

 return(
    <html lang="en">
       <body>
         ...
       </body>
    </html>
 )

}
```

**Note:** This was tested in Next.js 13 I'm not sure about other versions

I did have this custom ThemeContext I had created, but the error still happens even after I comment it out:

```
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import Providers from '@/redux/provider';
import MainHeader from '@/components/mainheader';
import SideBar from '@/components/sidebar';
// import { ThemeProvider } from '@/context/ThemeContext';
import { User } from '@/types/user';

interface layoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

// const user: User = {
//   theme: 'dark',
// };

const Layout: FC<layoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    // <ThemeProvider user={user}>
    <main>
      <MainHeader />
      <SideBar />
      <Providers>{children}</Providers>
    </main>
    // </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```